# Orion Context Broker Context subscriptions with Android client

Tags: android, fiware, fiware-orion

Is it possible to make context subscriptions to Orion Context Broker resources from an Android application? For  NGSI10 basic operations (updateContext and queryContext) I supose that any common android rest client can be used, but how can we subscribe through subscribeContext?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could be an option programming a nodejs component on server side which is subscribed to the Orion Context Broker and also implements websockets in order to perform the communication with the Android clients?

Comment: In addition to the answer that @LeandroGuillen has already provided, I think that your nodejs approach (or any other based on "bridging" REST notifications with websocket or other similar "webclient/app-friendly" notification mechanism) would work.

Answer (score 3):

Disclosure: I'm the co-founder of Bastly

Bastly is an **open source solution**, so you can deploy on your own instances our software and use it for free (AGPL2)

The hacker plan is enough to test it out without the hassle of deploying the instances, then is a paid service based on how many concurrent users/messages you send. Don't hesitate to ask us for startup plans, discounts, etc.

Register to get an APIKEY and you can test it out pushing objects to our ORION instance at the moment http://orion.bastly.com:1026/ and following the doc https://github.com/Bastly/bastly-sdk-android how to get updates based on a channel. I'll make a step-to-step guide for Orion in the next week.

We are working on allowing to config your own Orion instance from the user panel, it will be ready around next week

Ping me on alex@bastly.com for any help that you may need.

The specific code that handles the Orion subscription pushes to sockets is on Bastly/connector-rest:

https://github.com/Bastly/connector-rest

We use ZeroMQ to send messages across platforms and a translator from ZeroMQ to SocketIO for webs, chaski workers are in charge of that:

https://github.com/Bastly/chaski

And all the request are handled through Atahualpa that decides where to forward the messages using a data bus and an operations bus:

https://github.com/Bastly/atahualpa

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [bastly](http://bastly.com) service. It does exactly what you want and it already works with Orion.

Comment: Bastly could be an option for managing the subscriptions but it is not a free service...

Comment: I joined the conversation jvadillo! :) Bastly is Open Source, please read my anwer