# Is there a Cross Platform Mobile Push Notifications GE in Fiware?

Tags: fiware-orion

What is the recommended solution for cross platform mobile phone push notification in Fiware?

E.g. After one of these phone platform (e.g. ios, android, window phone) has registered certain OrionBorker's subscription service on e.g. ONCHANGE. Is there a GE in Fiware to provide the push notification?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no FIWARE GE that does this (to my knowledge).

Then although your question is slightly different, what is said in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29930412/orion-context-broker-context-subscriptions-with-android-client) also applies here: [bastly](http://www.bastly.com) can do push notifications to both mobile and web and read/subscribe from Orion Context Broker.