# FIWARE Orion Websocket support

Tags: android, ios, fiware, fiware-orion

I have seen in the Orion's Roadmap the **websocket** support for subscription.
In which state is it? I consider this feature is very interesting for Pub/Sub in mobile apps.

Answer (score 0):

As time of writing this (Orion 0.23.0), the feature has not been yet developed. If you find it useful, please add a +1 comment to [the corresponding issue at github](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/1181).

In the meanwhile, you can use some "bridging" software to convert between REST notifications and websockets, either your own one or platforms such as Bastly. Please have a look to [this Q&A post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29930412/orion-context-broker-context-subscriptions-with-android-client), which is addressing a very similar issue.